# PHP Random M or F

Tags: php

I would like to create a function to random between `M` or `F` characters.
How could I create an function to do that?

Comment: Do you want random only from M and F or random from all characters between M and F?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code to get `M` or `F` randomly:

```
return chr(rand(0, 1) ? 70 : 77);
```

Or a even shorter version suggested by @Maerlyn:

```
return rand(0, 1) ? 'F' : 'M';
```

Comment: nice and compact! I like it.

Comment: A simple `return rand(0, 1) ? 'F' : 'M';` would do, but I like the idea.

Comment: @Maerlyn Post it as an answer.

Comment: @phant0m I'd rather not, as it's just a minor (in my opinion) modification of *this* answer. OP should accept this one if he/she likes the idea.

Comment: I can hardly argue if you don't want to, but then Blauesocke could update his answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Like this for example?

```
function randMF() {
    $chars = array('M', 'F');
    return $chars[array_rand($chars)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
function randomString($length = 6) {
 $str = "";
 $characters = range('F','M');
 $max = count($characters) - 1;
 for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $rand = mt_rand(0, $max);
  $str .= $characters[$rand];
 }
 return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function randstr(){
    return substr(str_shuffle("FGHIJKLM"),0,1);
}
```

or

```
function randstr(){
    return chr(rand(70, 77)); //70 and 77 are char codes for M and F
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @fire's answer, I think this is what the OP wants:

```
$characters = range('F','M');
$max = count($characters) - 1;
$radnom_char = $characters[mt_rand(0, $max)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function whatever(){

    $random = rand ( 1 , 2 );

    if ($random == 1)
    { 
       $letter = 'M';
    }
    else
    {
       $letter = 'F';
    }

      return $letter
    }
```

This is just an easy way to do it.